# Kubernetes Killing Mongo Container

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes

We have a situation where Kubernetes is killing Mongo containers when it reaches max memory limit of the container. Even though its expected to K8s to work in that way but feel like Mongo is not reusing its memory as its keep on growing the memory usage day by day even though the user load & transactions are the same so what to check how we can limit the Mongo in reaching max memory of the container or flush Mongo memory at regular intervals.

I have tried to increase the memory which helped the pods to keep running a couple of more days before K8 killing it

```
     "containers": [
          {
            "name": "mongo",
            "image": "dockercentral.com:5870/com.public/mongodb:3.6",
            "ports": [
              {
                "containerPort": 27017,
                "protocol": "TCP"
              }
            ]      
"resources": {
              "limits": {
                "cpu": "1",
                "memory": "24Gi"
              },
              "requests": {
                "cpu": "250m",
                "memory": "24Gi"
              }
            }
   "name": "MONGO_SECURITY",
                "value": "true"
              }
            ],
            "resources": {
              "limits": {
                "cpu": "500m",
                "memory": "1Gi"
              },
              "requests": {
                "cpu": "150m",
                "memory": "256Mi"
              }
            },
```

Comment: What specific version of MongoDB server are you running? Have you set the cacheSizeGB (and if so, to what value)? As per the [MongoDB Production Notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/): If you run `mongod` in a container (e.g. `lxc`, `cgroups`, Docker, etc.) that does *not* have access to all of the RAM available in a system, you must set [`storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB) to a value less than the amount of RAM available in the container.

Comment: MongoDB 3.6 version,  cacheSizeGB value is not set thought it will consider container memory limits & auto allocate wiredTiger cache ..i have set wiredTigerCacheSizeGB now  .. will check whether it gonna work

Comment: There were some historical challenges reliably [detecting container memory with a generic approach](https://fabiokung.com/2014/03/13/memory-inside-linux-containers/) so the current recommendation is to set `wiredTigerCacheSizeGB` explicitly. If you set `wiredTigerCacheSizeGB` similar to the default (50% of available RAM - 1GB), memory usage should be more stable. NOTE: an improvement has been implemented in the MongoDB 4.1.9 development branch by way of [SERVER-16571](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-16571), which has been backported to the upcoming 3.6.13 and 4.0.9 server releases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what **Stennie from MongoDB, Inc.** wrote in comment to question.

this command in kube .yaml works for me:

```
      command:
        - "sh"
        - "-c"
        - >
          echo "storage:" >>  /etc/mongod.conf;
          echo "    wiredTiger:" >>  /etc/mongod.conf;
          echo "       engineConfig:" >>  /etc/mongod.conf;
          echo "          cacheSizeGB: 2" >>  /etc/mongod.conf;
          echo "replication:" >> /etc/mongod.conf;
          echo "  replSetName: YOUR_REPL_NAME" >> /etc/mongod.conf;
          mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf;
```

also there is a way to set it in runtime:

```
db.adminCommand( { "setParameter": 1, "wiredTigerEngineRuntimeConfig":"cache_size=2G"})
```

which also works just fine, but it looks easier through kuberneties yaml file because to issue a command you have to wait until mongo is up and running.

NOTE:
make sure that your:

```
      resources:
        limits:
          memory:
```

is allowing **extra 1G** for system.

Comment: setting ***wiredTigerCacheSizeGB*** helped in fixing the issue..thanks @Stennie.. & user2932688 sry guys for getting back late i was testing the change & waited for sometime in production to make sure fix is working.

Comment: @Panda im having this same issue when my mongodb pod restarts and im assumng becasues of high memory usage.  but my k8 containers dont have any resource limits. Im curious what you said the size of this wiredTigerCache to and does this still work for you

Comment: @Kay, Yes WiredTigerCache worked for me. I wonder why your container don't have resource limits its something common anyone use for a container.